# Is there an R or dplyr function which counts the rows which meet criteria for the current row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

vars = list(
  observations = 15,
  max_wait_time = 5,
  max_run_time = 10
)

df <- as_tibble(list(submit = round(runif(vars$observations, 1, vars$observations)), 
                wait = round(runif(vars$observations, 1, vars$max_wait_time)),
                run = round(runif(vars$observations, 5, vars$max_run_time)))) %>%
      arrange(submit) %>%
      mutate(id = c(1:vars$observations), .before = submit)

df <- df %>% mutate(start = submit + wait, end = start + run)
```

This script gives a tibble with some data like below:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 6
      id submit  wait   run start   end
   <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1      2     2     7     4    11
 2     2      3     1     8     4    12
 3     3      4     4     9     8    17
 4     4      4     3     9     7    16
 5     5      5     3     7     8    15
 6     6      6     4     8    10    18
 7     7      6     4     8    10    18
 8     8      9     5     7    14    21
 9     9     10     4     6    14    20
10    10     10     2     9    12    21
11    11     11     3     9    14    23
12    12     12     2     8    14    22
13    13     14     3     6    17    23
14    14     14     5     8    19    27
15    15     14     2     9    16    25
```

For each row I need to get a count of rows whose **start** value is between current row's **start** and **end** value (e.g. `some_row$start >= .$start & some_row$start < .$end` ). I have found that `pmap` could be useful for looping through all rows and counting all other rows which meet criteria based on current row's values, but I have no idea how to apply it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(new = map2_dbl(start, end, ~ sum(start >= .x  & start <= .y)))
```

---

Or using `Map` from `base R`

```
df$new <- unlist(Map(function(x, y) sum(df$start >= x & 
                df$start <= y), df$start, df$end))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:15, submit = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 14L), wait = c(3L, 4L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), run = c(7L, 
8L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L), 
    start = c(4L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 9L, 12L, 11L, 
    12L, 13L, 14L, 16L), end = c(11L, 14L, 13L, 17L, 16L, 19L, 
    13L, 16L, 19L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, it works :)
Maybe you also know how to increase speed of map? Because if I have around 1 million of records it takes some time to wait before I'll get final result.

Comment: @V.Kolesnik if it is a big dataset, then you may try a non-equi join from data.table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new = sum(.$start >= start & .$start < end))

#      id submit  wait   run start   end   new
#   <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1      2     2     7     4    11     7
# 2     2      3     1     8     4    12     7
# 3     3      4     4     9     8    17    10
# 4     4      4     3     9     7    16    10
# 5     5      5     3     7     8    15     9
# 6     6      6     4     8    10    18     9
# 7     7      6     4     8    10    18     9
# 8     8      9     5     7    14    21     7
# 9     9     10     4     6    14    20     7
#10    10     10     2     9    12    21     8
#11    11     11     3     9    14    23     7
#12    12     12     2     8    14    22     7
#13    13     14     3     6    17    23     2
#14    14     14     5     8    19    27     1
#15    15     14     2     9    16    25     3
```

Comment: Thanks, @RonakShah. It is also helpful. But still having issues with quite big data frame with 1M of rows.

Comment: @vkolesnik Does this help using `data.table` ? `setDT(df)[, new:= sum(df$start >= start & df$start < end), 1:nrow(df)]`

Comment: Still quite long, @ronak-shah. I have been waiting for almost 10 minutes with my data frame and just have stopped the operation with no success. Maybe there is some way to process such a big set by chunks?